# Is it bad class design if a child does not need all protected members of a parent class?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I am learning about classes, abtract classes, and inheritance in C++. I am writting a small personal proyect that plays Cluedo.

So far I am thinking about a base class:

```
class player
{
protected:
std::string name,character,position;
std::string* hand;
public:
//things he can do
};
```

And then have a computer player:

```
class computer:public player
{
private:
fakePlayer* spreadsheet;
public:
//things he can do
};
```

The computer is basically a player, which has an array of `fakePlayer`s, where fakePlayer is:

```
class fakePlayer:public player
{
std::string* hasNot; //card I know he doesn't have
std::string* possibly; //cards he may have
std::string* shown; //cards I hve shown to him
};
```

The `fakePlayer` does not need a `character`, or a `position`; does that mean that it is not a type player? The other thing I could to is having an abstract `class player` which only has a `name` and a `hand`, and then derived classes `class human:public player`, `class fakePlayer:public player`, and `class computer:public human`.

Is it more convenient to have a derived class that doesn't use some protected members? or Is it better to create a more general abstract class?

Comment: The child class *already* and *automatically* contains all its parent's members, and you cannot *prevent* this by any form of 'class design'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to force an unnatural (i.e., unnecessary) class hierarchy.  You may want to consider using interfaces instead of base classes.  (C++ core language doesn't distinguish an interface from a base class, it's a matter of convention and style and a bit of discipline.)

Comment: @user207421 I understand that the child automatically contains all it's parent's members; I could paraphrase my question as: If a child won't use all the protected members of the parent class, would it be more appropiate to have a more general parent class that contains only the members both classes use? Then the previous parent would now be a child of the new base class.

Comment: Sounds like you have two types of players - a human (or elf, if you prefer) and a computer.  Have one base class with the common functionality, and two derived classes.  One for the elf, err human, and one for the computer.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you have over designed your base class.

Answer (score 1):

If some of the data members of your base class are not relevant to your derived class, then your inheritance design probably needs some attention. (Strictly speaking, it's not wrong. However, it is probably not fully thought out.) Which you seem to have recognized, so that much is good.

How to resolve a situation like this often involves a few judgement calls. I would start by asking what should the base class (`player` in this case) embody? It seems reasonable to me for `player` to mean one of the players in the game, which is basically what you have coded. So how does this "fake player" fit into the picture? Does a fake player need to act like a player? Should fake players be capable of playing a game amongst themselves? If not, it probably should not inherit from `player`.

Another possibility is having a common base class for `player` and `fakePlayer` (including the possibility of `player` deriving from `fakePlayer`). Now the question to ask is what does this common base class embody? What do players and fake players have in common? Why should they have a common base class?

As you get deeper into your program, you might find a reason for a common base class. However, from the code you've shown, it looks like a fake player is nothing more than record keeping. It is not a player so much as notes *about* a player. That alone does not justify sharing a base class. They might share some auxiliary classes (such as a class for cards, rather than using strings), but not a base class. My next step for your code would be to drop "`:public player`" from the definition of `fakePlayer` (and probably rename the class) and go from there.

Comment: Thoughtful and well-written.